# syslinux output duplicated in QEMU serial console

Tags: boot, opensuse, qemu, serial-console, syslinux

Any idea why *syslinux* output is duplicated in QEMU serial console?

```
SeaBIOS (version rel-1.14.0-0-g155821a1990b-prebuilt.qemu.org)


iPXE (http://ipxe.org) 00:03.0 CA00 PCI2.10 PnP PMM+3FF8F290+3FEEF290 CA00
                                                                               


Booting from Hard Disk...

SYSLINUX 6.03 EDD 2014-10-06 Copyright (C) 1994-2014 H. Peter Anvin et al

SYSLINUX 6.03 2014-10-06 Copyright (C) 1994-2014 H. Peter Anvin et al
boot:boot:  

Loading linux...Loading linux...  ook
k
Loading initrd..Loading initrd....
```

QEMU was started this way:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -smp 2 -drive format=raw,file=/dev/sdb -vga none \
    -serial telnet:localhost:1234,server,wait -nographic
```

And...

```
telnet localhost 1234
```

I was modifying openSUSE boot media to work with serial console

```
diff -uNp /mnt/boot/x86_64/loader/syslinux.cfg{.orig,}
--- /mnt/boot/x86_64/loader/syslinux.cfg.orig   2021-03-19 01:05:00.000000000 +0100
+++ /mnt/boot/x86_64/loader/syslinux.cfg        2021-03-19 01:23:26.000000000 +0100
@@ -1,4 +1,6 @@
-default harddisk
+serial --unit=0 --speed=115200
+terminal --timeout=10 serial console
+default linux
 
 # hard disk
 label harddisk
@@ -7,7 +9,7 @@ label harddisk
 # install
 label linux
   kernel linux
-  append initrd=initrd splash=silent showopts
+  append initrd=initrd textmode=1 console=ttyS0,115200n81
 
 # upgrade
 label upgrade
@@ -42,7 +44,6 @@ label memtest
   menu label ->x memtest
   kernel memtest
 
-ui             gfxboot bootlogo message
 implicit       1
 prompt         1
 timeout                600
```

My quick & dirty notes https://gist.github.com/jirib/7970eed8431013983a8cf1c947041c2a

Answer (score 1):

You likely have two versions of syslinux binary present on the disk.  The first one the system boots is corrupted and fails.  Each time you see your boot screen start with `SYSLINUX 6.03 EDD`, that means an error has occurred.  I'm surprised your qemu instance run a second syslinux binary.